# Why does my cauliflower plant have leaves which are damaged and full of holes?

Tags: diagnosis, vegetables, raised-beds, brassicas, cauliflower

See attached picture of my cauliflower plant in my raised bed. Other plants are healthy but this one does not look as healthy. What could be the reason?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as though it's been ravaged by insects.  Are you sure you don't have cabbage worms, aphids etc attacking this plant.

Sometimes I see that the weakest plant in a group of plants gets attacked by insects leaving the more healthy ones alone.  That is it becomes the honey pot limiting damage to the other plants.

Answer (score 0):

You've got flea beetles.  They only last a short time but they love the brassicas and mustards.  I found that having a TRAP crop is the best way to divert these dudes from my 'cash' crops.